# Response timeout for webserver from public IP - Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, networking, web-server, port-forwarding

I'm at a loss on this one. I am trying to forward traffic to my pi located beneath two routers.

My network is structured like this:

> Public IP  56.xx.xx.xx
>
> ---
>
> router 1 (LAN Range 192.168.0.1-255)
>
> ---
>
> router 2 (DHCP reservation at 192.168.0.100)
>   (LAN Range 10.0.0.1-255)
>
> ---
>
> pi (static 10.0.0.100 tried apache, flask, python server on port 80)
>
> ---

I am certain that port forwarding is working. I was able to successfully forward traffic to my pc hosting an IIS site and also a mac hosting node http server but as soon as I try forwarding traffic to my pi I cannot see the site. I get a connection timeout. I flushed iptables so firewall shouldn't be a problem and to make things even more confusing, I am able to contact the pi via direct local IP address in a browser or even using my local network's DNS name from the pc and mac located on the 10. network.

Could there be any firewall or traffic rules that I am missing even after running `sudo iptables -F`?

Comment: this is not raspberry pi related question.
Double NAT not always works as intended, however mine working fine with HTTP and SIP. Can you access your RPI from your 192.168.0/24 network?

Comment: How would I be able to do that if the RPI is on a 10.0.0.0/24? Wouldn't it be inaccessible via IP address since it's behind another NAT? I tried it but I cant hit my pc or mac via direct IP either which makes sense because all of them are behind the second NAT.

Comment: Can you connect a PC on your 192.168.0.0/24 network? If so, from there you should be able to reach your RPI on 192.168.0.100:pppp (pppp is the port you forwarded to your 10.0.0.yyy (yyy =RPI static).

Comment: Ahh gottcha. Yeah, that works as expected. In addition I just setup an nginx server on my DNS box on the 10.0.0.x network and a reverse proxy to the PI using the PI's private 10.0.0.100 in the nginx config and it works.... However I want to forward traffic to my pi directly. It just seems like the PI is ignoring any traffic coming from off the network.